# toArray method of List with runtime type of the objects in the List

Tags: java, list, toarray

When using `javax.mail.Message#setRecipeints`, I noticed a thing for the first time and wanted to know more about it.

This is my code:

```
List<InternetAddress> ccRecipients = new ArrayList<InternetAddress>();
// have a valid and working 
// method that fills the list with the data (InternetAddress objects)
message.setRecipients(
         RecipientType.CC, ccRecipients.toArray(new InternetAddress[0]));
```

Here I am not getting why do we require to create a new `InternetAddress` array and pass the element at 0th index in the `toArray` method?

Can anyone explain why do we require this to be done?

I think it has something to do with this special `toArray` method.

I read the following from the API docs but didn't get the last part (in bold) :

*Like the toArray() method, this method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs. Further, **this method allows precise control over the runtime type of the output array, and may, under certain circumstances, be used to save allocation costs**.*

How does it save allocation costs?

Comment: You are not passing the 0th element, you are allocating a new array of length zero, and passing that.

Comment: but why do we need to do that, can't we simply pass the class name instead of creating array object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toArray()` without parameter returns type of `Object` but `toArray(T[] a)` returns type of `T[]`. This is a generic method of List.

Comment: Yes I know that, but why do we need that array there, can't we pass the class name only?

Comment: @Abu see my answer, it uses the array you pass in if it is large enough.

Comment: yes I know that, but I want the reason why do we do that, can't it infer from the class name that we can provide to the method

Comment: @Abu Because it gives you the option to reuse an existing array rather than make a new one. If the only option was to pass in the class name, the method would **have to** create a new array every time. By letting you pass in an array, you have more flexibility and are able to allocate space once, and then copy lists into the array multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) for the `ArrayList.toArray()` method you are using:

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
  if (a.length < size)
    // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
    return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
  System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
  if (a.length > size)
    a[size] = null;
  return a;
}
```

First off, you aren't passing in a reference to index 0, but a new array of length 0.  Assuming your list isn't empty, the new zero length array will be too small to hold it, and a new array of the correct type is created: `Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());`

You could pass in an array that was large enough to hold the entire list, and then the list would be copied into the array you provided: `System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);` As to whether this will save you allocation costs, it's hard to say. `System.arraycopy()` is native a method, i.e. platform dependent.  Without seeing the code it uses you just have to rely on the fact that native implementations should be more efficient in general and trust that the JVM writers know what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the method is an array that may receive the contents of the Collection, if it is big enough. I think that circumstances would be if you already had an array allocated that was large enough to hold the collection, that same array could be used instead of allocating a new one.

Note that your code is passing an array of length 0 -- that array will be returned only when the collection is empty. If there are any items in the List, a new array will be allocated and returned.

Answer (score 0):

To use it to save allocation costs the array argument has to be at least as long as the List. In that case, the data is copied into the array referenced by the argument. Suppose the List is always the same size, you always want it to be the same element type, and you only need one array at a time. You could reuse the same array, rather than creating a new on each time toArray is called.

In practice, it is more usual to create a new array each time, but if you use the List size rather than 0 toArray will be able to use it.